# App Center does not start

Tags: release-loki

App center is dead. I have no idea where to start troubleshooting.
I'm currently manually updating the system and is kept up to date....

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried removing and reinstalling appcenter but that didn't help either

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal and try to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Worked, easy fix to big problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install appcenter
```

Did the trick for me.

Comment: Note to readers: Please add a comment stating the reason for the downvotes and how to improve it.