# AppCenter doesn't start: Metadata files have errors

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

When I start AppCenter in GUI, an icon appears in the dock, and after a few seconds it silently crashes, without showing anything. When I start it from terminal, I get the following output:

```
[ERROR 13:25:43.613069] Client.vala:65: Metadata files have errors: /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/uz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I've already tried suggested answer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8676/app-center-does-not-start).
I'm not sure when the problem appeared. Still I can install packages via terminal without any problems.

I have the following ppa's (excluding elementary) in my sources.list.d:

```
#MYSQL
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-tools
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-5.7
#WINE
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main 
#ROS
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
#ELEMENTARY TWEAKS
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

The content of sources.list was never changed, but here's the short version (without commented lines):

```
deb http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted 
deb http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted 
deb http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe 
deb http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe 

deb http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse 
deb http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse 

deb http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse 

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: aptitude doesn't exist as a command on my elementary terminal...why?

Comment: @Antonio You can use apt instead, I think there will be no difference. Just type apt instead of aptitude. Aptitude was what I used. It is a 3rd party tool so you have to install it by yourself. sudo apt install aptitude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made

```
sudo aptitude purge appstream
sudo apt install appcenter
```

Solved the problem. But maybe simply deleting files in `/var/lib/app-info/yaml/` would solve the problem too, I don't know.